# Is it a bad practice to combine use of Task and IObservable in my C# application?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, system.reactive

I've recently gotten into Rx and I'm using it to help me pull data from several APIs in a data mining application.

I have an interface that I implement for each API, which encapsulates common calls to each API, e.g.

```
public interface IMyApi {

    IObservable<string> GetApiName(); //Cold feed for getting the API's name.

    IObservable<int> GetNumberFeed(); //Hot feed of numbers from the API

}
```

My question is around cold IObservables vs Tasks. In my mind, a cold observable is basically a task, they operate in much the same way. It strikes me as strange to be 'abstracting' a Task away as a cold observable, when you could argue that a Task is all you need. Also using a cold observable to wrap Tasks hides the nature of the activity, since the signature looks the same as a hot observable.

Another way I could represent the above interface is:

```
public interface IMyApi {

    Task<string> GetApiNameAsync(); //Async method for getting the API's name.

    IObservable<int> GetNumberFeed(); //Hot feed of numbers from the API

}
```

Is there some conventional wisdom on why I shouldn't mix and match between Tasks and IObservables?

Edit: To clarify - I've read the other discussions posted and understand the relationship between Rx and TPL, but my concerns are mainly about whether or not it's **safe** to combine the two in an application and whether it can lead to bad practice or threading and scheduling pitfalls?

Comment: This has been discussed a lot http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2542764/tpl-vs-reactive-framework

Comment: Hi thanks for responding, I've narrowed my question a bit in my edit.

Comment: What kind of safety issues are you afraid of?

Comment: Guess I'm chasing a red herring here huh...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no problem mixing the models, and in fact even the Rx team has included many adaptive operators in Rx. For example, `ToTask`, `ToObservable`, `SelectMany`, `DeferAsync`, `StartAsync`, `ToAsync`, etc. You can even `await` an `IObservable<T>` within an `async` method.

The primary difference that should affect your decision is cardinality:

`IObservable<T>` is [0,∞]

`Task<T>` is [0,1]

So if you need to represent only a single return value, then strongly consider using `Task<T>`.

Comment: Okay, thanks that's basically my feelings too. It's good to know the Rx team intended them to be interwoven.

Answer (score 6):

> My question is around cold IObservables vs Tasks. In my mind, a cold observable is basically a task, they operate in much the same way

It is important to note that this is *not* the case, they are very different. Here's the core difference:

```
// Nothing happens here at all! Just like calling Enumerable.Range(0, 100000000)
// doesn't actually create a huge array, until I use foreach.
var myColdObservable = MakeANetworkRequestObservable();

// Two network requests made!
myColdObservable.Subscribe(x => /*...*/);
myColdObservable.Subscribe(x => /*...*/);

// Only ***one*** network request made, subscribers share the
// result
var myTaskObservable = MakeATask().ToObservable();
myTaskObservable.Subscribe(x => /*...*/);
myTaskObservable.Subscribe(x => /*...*/);
```

Why is this important? Several methods in Rx such as `Retry` depend on this behavior:

```
// Retries three times, then gives up
myColdObservable.Retry(3).Subscribe(x => /*...*/);

// Actually *never* retries, and is effectively the same as if the
// Retry were never there, since all three tries will get the same
// result!
myTaskObservable.Retry(3).Subscribe(x => /*...*/);
```

So in general, making your Observables as *cold* will generally make your life easier.

### How can I make a Task Cold?

Use the Defer operator:

```
var obs = Observable.Defer(() => CreateATask().ToObservable());

// CreateATask called *twice* here
obs.Subscribe(/*...*/);
obs.Subscribe(/*...*/);
```

Comment: +1 for showing that `Task` is *hot*, but consider changing the `Defer` example to `FromAsync` instead.

Answer (score 4):

The difference between `Task` and `IObservable` is not hot vs. cold: `Task`-returning methods can pretty much be "cold" (return new `Task` on every call) or "hot" (always return the same `Task`), just like `IObservable`s.

The difference between the two is that `IObservable` represents a *sequence of results*, while `Task` represents a *single result*.

So, in cases when you'll always have a single result (or an error), use `Task`, when you can have any number of results, use `IObservable`.

Comment: Actually, this is a really good insight... I hadn't thought that a Task could be considered 'hot'.

Comment: This is true, but realistically nobody uses a cold `Task` (i.e., the `Task` constructor). It's pretty safe to say that `Task` is *hot* in general, especially in the world of `async/await`. It's the function that makes a `Task` cold; as soon as you've got a reference to a `Task`, you can pretty much bet that it's `hot`. Not true for `IObservable<T>` in general.

Comment: @DaveSexton Yeah, there are differences in how you can implement coldness using `Task` and `IObservable`. But I think those differences are not that important.

Comment: `Task` is still *hot*; by the time you get its reference it may have already completed. It's the deferring function that's making it *cold*. Wrapping anything in a function makes it *cold*, so you could do the same with a `hot` observable; e.g., `Observable.Defer`. So a *cold* `Task` is one that is constructed by the `Task` constructor, and you must start it manually for it to have any side effects, like calling `Subscribe` on an `IObservable<T>`.
http://davesexton.com/blog/post/Hot-and-Cold-Observables.aspx

Comment: My previous comment was in reference to the previous comment by @svick that was deleted. :)